# A weird : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

I've got a problem with a dynamic table. Here is the code :

```
public static Object[][] extractSCTableData(Hashtable<Integer,Colis> lColis) {
    Object[][] tableData = {{}};
    int i=0;
    Set<Integer>keySet = lColis.keySet();
    for (Integer currKey:keySet) {
        tableData[i][0]=lColis.get(currKey).expediteur;
        tableData[i][1]=lColis.get(currKey).noColis;
        tableData[i][2]=currKey;
        i++;
    }
    return tableData;
}
```

I've got an exception and i don't know why ... The error :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Apperently I don't know how declared my tab !
The weird thing it's that i have the same kind of method ( in an other class ) without the error.
The other method :

```
public static Object[][] extractSCTableData(Course[] lCourse)
        throws ExceptionColisInconnu {
    int nbCourse = lCourse.length;
    Object[][] tableData = { {} };
    for (int i = 0; i < nbCourse; i++) {
        short noColis = lCourse[i].noColis;
        String etat;
        org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb;
        String[] str = {};
        orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(str, null);
        G_Colis g_colis = (G_Colis) orb
                .string_to_object(lCourse[i].IORG_Colis);

        switch (g_colis.demandeEtat(noColis).value()) {
        case etatColis._enTransport:
            etat = "En cours";
            break;
        case etatColis._aDestination:
            etat = "Livré";
            break;
        case etatColis._auDepart:
        case etatColis._enAttenteDeTransport:
            etat = "Enregistrée";
            break;
        default:
            etat = "Non Défini";
            break;
        }
        tableData[i][0] = Short.toString(noColis);
        tableData[i][1] = etat;
    }
    return tableData;
}
```

If sombebody see something ...
Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `tableData[0][1]` and `tableData[0][2]` because  `Object[][] tableData = {{}};` defines an array with dimensions [1][0]

Comment: But for the second method I do `tableData[i][1] = etat;` and it's working fine ?!

Comment: Possibly it doesn't enter the loop. How have you tested the second method ?

Comment: Ouuups i'm sorry ! I was persuaded the second one was working, but i didn't test it .... Sorry !

I will certainly have the same problem then.

Then, how should I declare my `Object[][] tableData` ?
This way : `Object[][] tableData = new Object[lColis.keySet().length][3];` ?

Comment: Yes. This should work, if there are no more than three arrays

Comment: @user3757464 Thanks for using my answer w/o any reference, I appreciate "creative" commons!

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[][] tableData = new Object[lColis.keySet().length][3];
```